# what is that popup window in react native?

Tags: react-native

would you please help me. i'm trying to something like that and right now can't think correctly. i don't wanna do that with view's. it looks like drawer navigation but i wont navigate anywhere. i just want that users can select specs for product. is there any react native package for that or something. what is called that menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-native-modal` have animation, so you can use this module for mimic drawer menu style. Example you can try here https://snack.expo.io/@vasylnahuliak/2e3f3f

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

function App() {
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.root}>
      <Button title="Show modal" onPress={toggleModal} />

      <Modal
        isVisible={isModalVisible}
        animationIn="fadeInRight"
        animationOut="fadeInRight">
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
          <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={toggleModal} />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 250,
  },
  modalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 150,
    width: '50%',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'tomato',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`react-native-modal`](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal). Then styling for the modal can look similar to:

```
 modal: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    paddingBottom: 0, 
    marginBottom: 0, 
    marginLeft: 20, //depends how much space you want on the left side of the screen
    marginRight:0,
    
    flex: 1,
},
```